# Простой и бесплатный GUI

Tags: gui

Подскажите пожалуйста какие есть GUI (язык программирования любой можно) для windows для которых не надо писать много кода вручную ?

c++ и GTK как то совсем не понравились, вот пример хеллоуворда:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void button_clicked(GtkWidget
    * widget, gpointer data)
{
  g_print("Button was clicked!\n");
}

static gboolean delete_event(GtkWidget * widget, GdkEvent * event, gpointer data)
{
  g_print("Delete event occurred\n");

  return FALSE;
}

static void destroy(GtkWidget * widget, gpointer data)
{
  g_print("Destroy signal was sent\n");
  gtk_main_quit();
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  GtkWidget * window;
  GtkWidget * button;
  const gchar * title = "Hello World!";
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), title);
  gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "delete_event", G_CALLBACK(delete_event), NULL);
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(destroy), NULL);
  button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Quit");
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(button_clicked), NULL);
  g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_destroy), G_OBJECT(window));
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), button);
  gtk_widget_show(button);
  gtk_widget_show(window);
  gtk_main();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Язык программирования любой можно?

     #!/usr/bin/wish
     wm title . {Hello, World!}
     pack [button .b -text Quit -command exit -padx 2cm]

Пример, конечно, под linux, но и tcl/tk и под винды есть. И работает нормально. (Разумеется, это можно и на C переписать. Строк будет немного больше. Но не сильно больше)

Comment: Это, по-вашему, много кода? Это вы еще через WinAPI не пробовали программировать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Что значит много кода вручную?

Вы посмотрите сами. Списочек я сейчас предоставлю.

1. [MFC](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MFC);
2. [Qt](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt);
3. [GTK+](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK%2B);
4. wxWindows, ныне [wxWidgets](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WxWidgets);
5. [FLTK](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLTK)
6. [Ultimate++](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate%2B%2B)

Попробуйте на каждом сделать свой Хеллоу Ворлд и оцените какой из тулкитов нравится больше.

Comment: ну вот на c# :

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Hello World!";
        }

вручную я написал только 

    label1.Text = "Hello World!";

все остальное сгенерировалось автоматически (кинул на форму кнопку и label)
только на .net, Winforms вроде бы только в платной версии Visual Studio

Comment: Э-э-э.... Вам тады нужно на VCL писать под Emcarcadero RAD C++ Builder... Дело в том, что в С++ в изначальной библиотеки нет никаких граф. средств. Они все прикручиваются сторонними библиотеками. И каждый из разработчиков инструментальных средств разработки пиарит свою разработку. Не удивительно, что MSVC++ по дефолту MFC подсовывает. Так же и Билдер по умолчанию заточен на работу с VCL. И в нем можно писать именно так, как и Ваш пример на шарпе. Другой вопрос, что билдер нужно *как бы* покупать.

Answer (score 2):

На текущий момент, самый прогрессивный GUI под Windows - это WPF под .NET. Для Hello World код не требуется вообще. Нужно в проект по умолчанию, в разметку добавить текст:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Hello World!" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: а он бесплатен? точнее для того чтобы пользоваться WPF не нужно покупать Visual Studio?

Comment: Visual Studio Express бесплатен. Но можно и без него, хотя это неудобно.

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studio 2012 Express для Windows Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/rus/downloads#d-2012-express)

Visual Studio Express 2012 для Windows Desktop позволяет создавать мощные приложение для настольных систем на языках C#, Visual Basic и C++. Вы можете использовать такие клиентские технологии, как Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF), Windows Forms и Win32. После установки вы можете использовать продукт в течении 30 дней. Для использования продукта по истечении 30 дней необходимо зарегистрироваться и получить бесплатный ключ продукта.

Answer (score 0):

Python и tkinter

к примеру:

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
tkinter.Label(root,text="Hi world").place(x=0,y=0)
root.mainloop()
```